# ARM Cortex M4 - GCC - Limit use of FPU Registers (eg s0-s15)

Tags: arm, fpu

is there a possibility to instruct the GCC compiler not to use all FPU registers on the ARM Cortex M4? The list file shows randomly used registers out of the 32 FPU registers (there is no obvious logic in the selection of the registers). I want to speedup my DSP function not to save always all 32 FPU registers on the stack.

Comment: There is the assembly language for that purpose.

Comment: Are you doing your DSP stuff in (inline) assembly? Doesn't the compiler generate optimal register usage for C code? Can you show an example?

Comment: gcc is open source, you can modify it to not do that

Comment: while in there you can/will see if there is code to do that and what the flag/option is

Comment: Have you read about the lazy stacking of FPU registers ?